# 10 fold cross validation with weka api

Tags: machine-learning, weka, cross-validation

How can I make a classification model by 10-fold cross-validation using Weka Api.

Should I cross validate model first : e.g.

```
 evaluation.crossValidateModel(classifier, trainingSet, 10, Random(1))
```

and then build a new classifier based on this trainedSet. e.g

```
 NaiveBayes nb2 = new NaiveBayes();  
 nb2.buildClassifier(train);
```

and then save and use this model (nb2)?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing concepts. Cross validation is used to test the performance of learning techniques over a dataset. The common procedure is to perform CV using the whole dataset with 10 folds usually. Then you can see which learning technique is obtaining better performance. You can use that technique to learn a model over the whole dataset for future predictions.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)

Comment: Yes, so far as I know, you can create a model using e.g. 10 fold cross validation (option in weka) and see correctly classified instances in your dataset- based on which you see the performance of your learning technique. But if you want to do the same thing in java, should you train/test your dataset using for e.g NaiveBayes technique and then use that set to build the model?